# Using Google custom search with existing form element

Tags: php, wordpress, search, google-custom-search

In my wordpress theme I have search page designed properly for wordpress native search and this is my form design for `searchform.php`.

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search">
        <label for="s" class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Search', 'checkout' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="field" name="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search here...', 'checkout' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'checkout' ); ?>" />
    </form>
```

Now, for moths I've tring to use Google custom search functionality while keeping the same form design. But I really didn't find a way to use Google search with existing form element.

Example Google CSE code that I'm using -

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'partner-pub-123456:78990125';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

But the `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` is breaking everything. I'm actually trying to use the overlay design of custom search. Can anyone help me out about how I can keep my existing search form design while using Google Custom search?

Comment: When you open your browser with the second code (Script CSE) you can check the html generated, the most important are the hidden inputs (contains your partner ID and settings of CSE). Why don't try to copy these inputs within your original form? Don't forget to change the value of the attribute "action".

Comment: then can I remove the `<gcse:search></gcse:search>` section from my code so that the form doesn't get generated automatically?

Comment: Exactly, if you want customize your form, I don't know another way.